# MacRuby issue with checkbox

Tags: ruby, xcode, macruby

I want to check the status of a checkbox within my program. When I code an `if` statement to check what its current state is, it automatically "checks" the box and continues with the first option, even if it originally is false. Code below

```
def execute (sender)
    if checkboxF = true
        then
            print label.stringValue = "Valid"
        else
            print label.stringValue = 'Invalid'
    end
end
```

Before I "execute" the checkboxes are not checked, but when the code is run, it automatically "checks" the box, and continues with the first option only.

Thanks!

Comment: Are `print` and `then` typically used in macruby?

Comment: I've typically have seen "Puts" but I prefer "print" as it makes more sense to me, and doesn't seem to have difference in execution.

Comment: how do you assign value to checkboxF?